# Getting AJAX to talk to PHP using post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to get my Ajax code to talk to my PHP file before returning back to the same page.

I want my form to be filled in and as soon as send is hit, it talks to my AJAX code, which therefore talks to the PHP file before returning with a success or failure message to end user.

The Ajax code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {  
        $(".submit").click(function() {  
            // validate and process form here
            var fname = $("#fname").val() ;
            var lname = $("#lname").val();
            var aemail = $("#aemail").val() ;
            var year = $("#year").val();
            var club = $("#club").val() ;
            var position = $("#position").val();
            var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&fname=' + fname + '&lname=' + lname + '&aemail='      + aemail + '&year=' + year + '&club=' + club + '&position=' + position;  


            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "acad_process.php",  
                data: dataString,  
                success: function(){      
                    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
                    $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
                    .append("<p>Thank you. We will be in touch soon.</p>")  
                };
                return false;

                error: function(){
                    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
                    $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Failed!</h2>")  
                    .append("<p>Sorry, your form returned an error! Please try again.</p>")  
                    .hide()  
                    .fadeIn(1500, function() {  
                    });
                };
                return false;      
            });  
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. As I am new to AJAX. Thanks

The issue appears to be PHP because on further investigation I get a error 500 omn the PHP page, and nothing gets returned to my page. The PHP code is:

```
    <?php

   $email_to = "example@domain.co.uk";

   if (!empty($_POST))
   {
   $fname = $_POST["fname"];
   $lname = $_POST["lname"];
   $email_from = $_POST["aemail"];
   $year = $_POST ["year"];
   $club = $_POST ["club"];
   $position = $_POST ["position"];

   $email_subject = "Enquiry";

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers = "From: $email_from . \n";
$headers = "Reply-To: $email_from . \n";

$message = "<p> You have received a message!</p>";
    $message .= "<p><strong>First Name:</strong>" . $fname . "</p>";
    $message .= "<p><strong>Surname:</strong>" . $lname . "</p>";
    $message .= "<p><strong>School Year:</strong> " . $year . "</p>";
    $message .= "<p><strong>E-Mail:</strong>" . $aemail ."</p>";
    $message .= "<p><strong>Club:</strong> " . $club . "</p>";
    $message .= "<p><strong>Position:</strong>" . $position . "</p>";

    ini_set("sendmail_from",$email_from);
    mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers, '-f'.$email_from);
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: did you check in browser if php file is responding http code 200 and is reachable?

Comment: what is the question? what is your problem?

Comment: `data: 'dataString',` needs to be `data: dataString,`

Comment: I have removed the ' by datastring, this was how it was before I just added them to see if they made a difference.. The PHP code is reachable, just doesn't seem to be reached through the AJAX. If I put form action="acad_process.php" it will send the form to the page and send the email.

Comment: notme: my question is what is wrong with the AJAX code, which is stopping it sending to the PHP file. Apologies, for not being clear.

Comment: I don't think you need the `return false;`'s, another note that might be helpful to you, is try watching the XHR tab inside the Chrome Dev console, and see if anything popups up when you click submit.

Answer (score 0):

try changing url: 'acad_process.php' to url: '/acad_process.php'

Also make sure you don't have any syntax errors in acad_process.php

Answer (score 0):

You are passing data using GET method. Below is an example to pass data using POST method

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
  }).success(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Comment: I have 'POST' after type, so doesn't this get data using the post method and not the get method?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".submit").click(function() {  
            // validate and process form here
            var fname = $("#fname").val() ;
            var lname = $("#lname").val();
            var aemail = $("#aemail").val() ;
            var year = $("#year").val();
            var club = $("#club").val() ;
            var position = $("#position").val();
            var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&fname=' + fname + '&lname=' + lname + '&aemail='      + aemail + '&year=' + year + '&club=' + club + '&position=' + position;  


            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "acad_process.php",  
                data: dataString,  
                success: function(){      
                    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
                    $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
                    .append("<p>Thank you. We will be in touch soon.</p>")  
                },
                error: function(){
                    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
                    $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Failed!</h2>")  
                    .append("<p>Sorry, your form returned an error! Please try again.</p>")  
                    .hide()  
                    .fadeIn(1500, function() { });
                }      
            });  // end of ajax
        }); // end of click listener
}); // end of doc ready
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this, now when submit form but without a valid e-mail it rejects it and presents the error message. However if I present a valid e-mail, it doesn't seem to do anything and just wipes the form. Thanks

Comment: What does your html look like?